# Url.Action combines previous URL with current route parameters in JavaScript in VS IDE

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, routes, url.action

I am generating an URL in JavaSctipt.
The first time I generate this URL I get the correct URL:
E.g. `**http://localhost:54415/NffCall/Details/DK/6607726**`

But the next time I generate the link I get the previous link combined with current parameters:
E.g. `http://localhost:54415/NffCall/Details/DK/6607726/DK/6608146`

The code which genrates my URLs looks like this:

```
var actionUrlBase = '@Url.Action("Details", "NffCall")';
var actionUrl = actionUrlBase + '/' + countryCode + '/' + orderNumber;
window.location.href = actionUrl;
```

**What shall I do to generate the correct link every time?**

EDIT:
I will just paste how the RouteCollection looks like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CountryCodeOrderNumberDetails",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{countryCode}/{orderNumber}",
        defaults: new { controller = "NffCall", action = "Details", countryCode = (string)null, orderNumber = (int?)null },
        constraints: new { countryCode = "[a-zA-Z]{2}", orderNumber = "[0-9]+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: i wouldn't build the url in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Helper @Url.RouteUrl instead.

```
var actionUrlBase = '@Url.RouteUrl("Default",new {action="Details", controller= "NffCall"},Request.Url.Scheme)';
var actionUrl = actionUrlBase + '/' + countryCode + '/' + orderNumber;
window.location.href = actionUrl;
```

This site explains it very well: http://www.patridgedev.com/2011/08/22/subtleties-with-using-url-routeurl-to-get-fully-qualified-urls/

Comment: Hi Djavier, thank you for your reply, but it seems that your code behave exactly the same way as my current code, so the problem persists.

Comment: What if you try by @Url.RouteUrl("Default",new {action="Details", controller= "NffCall"},Request.Url.Scheme), this will definetly get you the Url Scheme for the routing configuration you set.

Comment: Hi Djavier, it seems like the last code you provided here in the comment makes my code work. I don't really understand why your last code works, and why my code didn't work before. But it seems to work as it should now. So this might be an answer.

Comment: Glad it helps, there a some strange things when working with the routing and rendering urls using the helpers. i've been through this fellow!
Please vote up the answer!

Comment: Thank you Djavier, I have edited your answer to put the code from the comment there. I hope your code will work out in production on the server as well. Thank you.